# css transform displays scrollbar when not needed

Tags: html, css, zooming, transform, css-transforms

We are having a feature of increasing/decreasing zoom level of content. When user increases zoom, we are increasing scale of css property `transform`. When content is zoomed in then parent div displaying scroll-bar even not needed.

[image]

Please check the code and fiddle below:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="viewport">
  <div id="zoomDiv">
    <p style="width:250px;height:150px;background-color:yellow">
    hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j fs fsd fsdf hsjd hs jdfhsdf hsf j f
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="transformDiv(0.1)" id="increase">&nbsp;+&nbsp;</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="transformDiv(-0.1)" id="deccrease">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</a>

<script>
var d = 1;
function transformDiv(n) {

    d = d + n;
    document.getElementById("zoomDiv").style.transform = "scale("+d+")";

}
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#viewport{width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000;background-color:#FFF;overflow:auto}
#zoomDiv{transform}
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/hyvr7bwn/

Issue occurring in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hyvr7bwn/1/), turns out it needed the following CSS code for it to be aligned correctly. This just keeps the content to the left when zooming in so that there is no wasted space and the scroll does not show up when unwanted.

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left; 
float:left;
```